# В чем здесь проблема с внедрением зависимости? Почему здесь нужен параметр запроса?

Tags: python, fastapi

[image: Почему здесь нужен параметр запроса?]

```
GetSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

```
@app.post('/blog', status_code=201)
def create(request: BlogModel, session: Session = Depends(dependency=db.GetSessionLocal)):
    new_blog = db.BlogMap(title=request.title, body=request.body)
    session.add(new_blog)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(instance=new_blog)
    return new_blog
```

Я же внедрил зависимость Depends, а не query param, почему нужен какой-то local_kw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе примеров с официального сайта FastAPI: [SQL (Relational) Databases](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/)

Нужно создать отдельную функцию, которая будет вызывать `GetSessionLocal()` (в официальной документации `SessionLocal`) и передавать наружу через `yield`. Эту функцию уже нужно указать как зависимость через параметры:

```
# Копипаста частей примеров из документации
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

...

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_email(db, email=user.email)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)
```

На вашем коде (имена переменных и функций поменял под свое видение, так же я бы поменял `GetSessionLocal` просто на `SessionLocal`):

```
def get_session_local():
    session = db.GetSessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()


@app.post('/blog', status_code=201)
def create(request: BlogModel, session: Session = Depends(dependency=get_session_local)):
    new_blog = db.BlogMap(title=request.title, body=request.body)
    session.add(new_blog)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(instance=new_blog)
    return new_blog
```